# Need documentation on RouterDialog, Skill State, SkillContext and SemanticAction Class

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

I am looking for a documentation and code example on how following classes are can be used in the code. I am building a bot using nodejs v4 sdk.

SemanticAction Class
SkillState class
SkillContext
RouterDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely going to be closed, but I'll point you in the right direction, to the extent possible.

- SemanticAction - No docs are available for this, although [this kind of covers it](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/handbook/events/). [Here's the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/semanticaction?view=botbuilder-ts-latest). And [here's how it's used in Virtual Assistant](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/search?q=semanticaction&type=Code)
- SkillState - No docs for this. This is [just a model and does nothing more than store the state of a skill](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/f41fc0689bfe1135ad237879e638614f8bd2a36a/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/typescript/generator-botbuilder-assistant/generators/skill/templates/sample-skill/src/models/skillState.ts)
- SkillContext - No docs for this. This is [context to share between Bots and Skills](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/lib/typescript/botbuilder-skills/src/skillContext.ts)
- RouterDialog - No docs for this. It pretty much does what the name says and [routes the user through dialog flows](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/11efb3988a51c53b1012488b6b94356661d11dee/lib/typescript/botbuilder-solutions/src/dialogs/routerDialog.ts)

There are little to no docs for this for a couple of reasons:

1. VA is still in preview and development priority is more or less `C# > TypeScript > Docs`
2. The main docs are [here](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/index), but you're asking for documentation about very specific classes, which is unlikely to exist for nearly any SDK. For the most part, you need to read through the code to see how it works.